# Register call for socketChannel for same selector throws exception

Tags: java, nio

I register a socketchannel with a selector, when I cancel the key for that socketchannel & selector, that key remains invalid forever. So, future calls to add that socketchannel to selector throws CancelledKeyException.

```
Selection key = channel.register(selector, ops, this);
key.cancel();
key = channel.register(selector, ops, this);
```

Documentations states the same,

```
If this key has already been cancelled then invoking this method has no 
effect. Once cancelled, a key remains forever invalid.
```

So, I thought I was supposed to obtain another "Selection Key" but it seems impossible. Each channel creates a unique key for each selector when you register, but when you cancel that key, it wont remove the key from channel's key set. So, you cannot use that socketchannel & selector pair ever.

Is it correct? This implementation makes no sense, so I hope I miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those odd ones. Somewhere deep in the documentation which I can never find when I look for it is the statement that cancels are only processed on the next `select()`. So you would have to call `selectNow()` after the cancel and before the second `register()`.

But why you're doing this at all without an intervening `select()` is a mystery. Don't cancel the key, don't re-register: just change its `interestOps`.

Comment: It was for load balancing. A thread accepts socketchannel, reads first message, removes from its selector, decides which worker should get that channel, sends the channel to destination worker. So, if dest is itself, that makes the problem. I can handle that with a dest == itself check but I wanted to know if this SelectionKey really works this way. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: That's correct, you only need to cancel if you're moving it to a different Selector, so `if (dest != itself) { key.cancel(); }`. If it's the same `Selector`, the subsequent `register()` will actually return the same key with updated `interestOps` and `attachment`.